# Laravel Eloquent - Find and Other queries

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Why can't I use `find`with other queries? I want to be able to say find something where `id = 2` and `otherColumn = thisValue`. However, if I use `find(2)` and add the other query, then the sql query I get is `where 'id' = ?` and returns all ids. Why?!

Thanks

Comment: When you use find it doesn't return all ids, unless you use `OR WHERE` and mess up the query. So show the query you builder as well as the raw SQL that you would like to run.

Comment: i'm curious. find(3) is already retrieving a specific row (row with primary key equals 3), why would you want to put another where after?

Comment: You probably do this: `Model::find(2)->where('x','=','y')->get();` which is in fact equal to: `Model::find(2); Model::where('x','=','y')->get();` - you simply run 2 separate queries then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` with other queries but you don't need to use other queries with `find` because `find` method query into database using the `primary key` and if you have one user with a primary key for example, `id=1` then it couldn't be twice, means it must be unique and use of other queries with `find` is useless. The `find` method in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` calls the `find` method of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class and that method is given below:

```
public function find($id, $columns = array('*'))
{
    if (is_array($id))
    {
        return $this->findMany($id, $columns);
    }

    $this->query->where($this->model->getKeyName(), '=', $id);

    return $this->first($columns);
}
```

If you use something like this:

```
User::where('username', 'someuser')->find(1);
```

It'll work (`find` should be called at last, it calls `first` and `first` calls `get`) but it's not useful in this case; with `find`. Primary key could be any field; not only `id` and `getKeyName` retrieves it.

Answer (score 0):

`find($id)` automatically finds the record with the same value in your `$primaryKey` column, `$primaryKey` can be set in your model. If you wish to use other query, you should use `where()`

Your query should be like this:

```
Model::where('id','=',2)->where('otherColumn','=','thisValue')->get();
```

Comment: Yes, I know i can do that. I meant why can't I use `find(2)` for the id, and the `where` for my other clause?

Comment: How did you write the code? If you do `Model::where('field','=','value')->find($id)`, it actually works.